# Which api to use for interactive maps in my android app

Tags: android, jquery, html, google-maps

I want to make an android app (using java) which has interactive maps (like ammaps, which can be used with HTML5/jQuery mobile. Refer to http://www.ammap.com/).

On the world map different areas will be marked/colored/tagged based on some set of values. For example: Different countries will be shaded with different colors depending on the population value stored in the database(i will be using SQLite).

But i don't want to use HTML5/jQuery Mobile in my application.

Can I develop an application having interactive maps using Google Map APIs', or is there any other better alternative for Google Map APIs'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps api v2 is best. and very simple to integrate. Follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) tutorial by Lars Vogel. This must help.

Comment: yes, the map will be exactly like google maps application, fully interactive. :)